# Eclipse Ctrl+Space stopped working and a yellow rectangle shows up sometimes

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, code-completion

Every once in a while when I am coding in Eclipse, Ctrl + Space **stops working**. It just displays **"No completions available"** with red text in the bottom status-bar whenever I try.

In addition to this, there is some strange code highlighting that can occur. I am not aware of why it happens, how it happens, or what it's purpose is. But I know how it looks (See screenshot)

[image: Weird syntax highlighting in Eclipse]

These problems are always related, whenever Ctrl + Space stops working, that weird highlighting has a tendency to show up. And whenever that shows up, I know that code completition is not working.

I guess this mode is activated by me pressing some keyboard combination that I am unaware of.

I believe this problem is not associated only with one type of project (for example Android or Swing).

**How do I get rid of the Ctrl + Space problem and the weird highlighting without restarting Eclipse?**

Comment: I have just discovered this issue myself. It disappears if I close and reopen the file. Other open files don't seem affected. Still, the issue quickly reappears for a given file once I call completion on parts of the code. In my case, it seems to be when calling it after the "new" keyword.

Comment: Solution: Use IntelliJ :)